# SQL: Calculate the number of Days in a Month with no stock

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query than can calculate the number of days, in a given month, that a particular stock item was unavailable (ie: No. = 0).

Currently, I have developed a query that can calculate the number of days it has been from today's date where stock has been unavailable but what I am trying to actually calculate is, during a month, how many days was stock quantity = 0.  ie:  Month of Jan - on Jan 5, Jan 7 and Jan 20 there was no stock for Item A - this means that the number of days out of stock was = 3.

**Extra Details:**

Currently, I am basing my query in determining stock levels of the last transaction (ie: if, at the last transaction, the QTY of Stock = 0) then calculate the number of days between the transaction date and today.

```
Select [StockItems].StockCode, 

Case When SUM([StockItems].Qty_On_Hand)=0 Then (Datediff(day, GETDATE(),MAX([Transactions].TransactionDate))) ELSE 0 END AS 'Days Out of Stock', 

From dbo.[Transactions]

INNER JOIN [StockItems]
  ON [Transactions].[AccountLink] = [StockItems].[StockLink]

Where [StockItems].StockCode LIKE '%XXX%' 
AND [Transactions].TransactionDate>31/10/14

Group By [StockItems].StockCode
```

**My Thoughts**
There are different sorts of transactions - one of which is a good received transaction.  Perhaps it is possible to calculate the days where Stock Qty was zero and a transaction occurred then count that date until goods were received.

Thoughts?

Thank You.

Comment: could you provide some samples of your data?

Comment: Explain your table.   You say you are looking for "No. = 0", but there is no reference to a "No." column in your query.  Describe what you are looking for in terms of columns in your table, not the abstract concepts they represent.

Comment: Provide table details and some dummy data

Comment: start by creating a list of the days in the required time period.
then calculate the stock level on each day. finally count those that are 0. might be easier than the approach you are going for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT([StockItems].Qty_On_Hand 
From dbo.[Transactions]
INNER JOIN [StockItems] ON [Transactions].[AccountLink] = [StockItems].[StockLink]
WHERE [StockItems].Qty_On_Hand)=0
```